# how can the treebin read val when the treebin is writing in concurrencthashmap in java8?

Tags: java-8

Java version: 8

read operation:

```
    TreeBin.java
     // Simplifed Code
    /**
     * Returns matching node or null if none. Tries to search
     * using tree comparisons from root, but continues linear
     * search when lock not available.
     */
    final Node<K,V> find(int h, Object k)
```

write operation:

```
ConcurrencyHashmap.java
// Simplifed Code
/** Implementation for put and putIfAbsent */
final V putVal(K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent) {
    synchronized (f) {
       p = ((TreeBin<K,V>)f).putTreeVal(hash, key, value)) != null)
     }
}
```

The problem is: the key word synchronized, lock the treebin, so how can the function find() can be execute?
Why not to wait unlock?

Comment: miss the point ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is. Please [edit] your question with a more detailed description of the problem you have. Also add the source code you have and/or fully name the classes you use from the java SDK.

Comment: If I get your question correctly, the code which you didn’t post contains a call to `find` without using `synchronized`. You seem to lack the necessary understanding of what `synchronized` does and how it must be used. We can not give you a tutorial on this topic.